# TikZ: Drawing directed trees using tree layout, child{...}-syntax and lualatex

Tags: luatex, tikz-trees

There seems to be no way to draw *directed* edges using the new (?) tree graph layout and the child-syntax.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\tikzset{
  ->, % doesn't work
  nodes={draw, circle, minimum size = .5cm},
  >=Stealth[], % doesn't work
}

\begin{document}

\tikz[tree layout,
edge from parent/.style={draw,-latex}, % doesn't work
-> % doesn't work
] {
  \node {$\land$}
  child {
    node {$\lnot$}
    child {
      node {$a$}
    }
  }
  child {
    node {$\rightarrow$}
    child {
      node {$b$}
    }
    child {
      node {$c$}
    }
  };
}

\end{document}
```

Prove me wrong!

[image]

*EDIT*: I think I do use the new graph layout engine because using the conventional `tikzpicture` environment, the tree looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome! You don't actually appear to be using the `graph` syntax or libraries at all. You are using the ordinary syntax used for non-graph trees.

Comment: @cfr In the section "The Tree Layouts", the TikZ/PGF manual also shows the child syntax. I think I do use it.

Comment: No. Read it in context. That is there for comparison. The next example is introduced by saying that it illustrates the equivalent in graph syntax.

Comment: The trouble is that you are mixing the graph stuff with the regular trees stuff. You are not specifying the tree itself using the graph syntax, even though you are requesting a graph layout. I guess that specifying `tree layout` makes some ordinary changes as well as enabling the graph drawing stuff. So those changes have an effect, even though you don't ever draw a graph.

Comment: The passage you are referring to on page 406 of the manual starts `As described in Section 29.2, ...` i.e. when we explained how to draw regular tress.... The first words on top of 407 are `or in graph syntax:...` and the manual then draws the same tree using the new syntax. The example at the bottom of 406 is used to relate the new syntax to the familiar, old syntax. That old syntax is not, itself, being used to draw a graph. Only the second example (which produces an identical tree) is drawing a graph using the graph-drawing facilities.

Comment: The thing is that this syntax did what I wanted - making beautiful trees - except directing the edges. I was familiar with the new `a -> {b...}` syntax before, but couldn't use math mode, so I thought I have to switch to the old one.

Comment: Well, you can use maths. I couldn't figure that out either. But, thanks to a comment, I got that to work. (See answer below.) Or, just don't use the graph drawing environment and stick to the syntax you're using. Then make whatever adjustments you need to get the tree as you want it. The point is, that putting the old syntax in an environment which expects the new syntax is probably not going to work all that well. I'm surprised that it works as well as it does, to be honest.

Comment: I don't get the problem with overlapping nodes you show in your question. If I just use the old syntax, everything works fine. I've edited my answer to add this approach as well.

Comment: ... Except if I load `graphdrawing` anyway. I've asked [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262490/is-it-possible-to-draw-a-tree-using-standard-syntax-without-overlapping-if-grap) about the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using graph syntax, directed edges are specified within the tree specification itself. For example,

```
{ r -> a }
```

indicates a directed edge from `r` to `a`.

The whole point of the graph drawing libraries is that you specify the relationships and let Lua figure out the detailed structure.

Using this syntax, the directed edges are no problem. And, thanks to [Gonzalo Medina's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262413/tikz-drawing-directed-trees-using-tree-layout-child-syntax-and-lualatex/262416?noredirect=1#comment629315_262416), I'm now able to get mathematical content into the nodes as well.

So, for example, using the graph syntax, I can produce

[image: graph]

using this specification:

```
% modified from Gonzalo Medina's comment (below)
\tikz [tree layout] \graph [math nodes, nodes={draw, circle, minimum size = .5cm}, sibling sep=0pt]
{aaaa [as=$\land$] -> {aa [as=$\lnot$] -> a , aaa [as=$\rightarrow$] -> {b , c}} };
```

If your graphs are all *trees* i.e. have a single root, you might like to use a specialised tree-drawing package such as `forest`, `qtree` or `tikz-qtree` instead. If they are not all trees, you can still do this but only by tricking the package into thinking you are really drawing a tree, so it gets more complicated.

For your tree, for example, the `forest` specification looks like this:

```
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    edge = {->},
    circle,
    minimum size=5mm,
    inner sep=0pt,
    draw,
    math content,
    tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
    anchor=center
  },
  [\land
    [\lnot
      [a]
    ]
    [\rightarrow
      [b]
      [c]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: tree]

Here including maths in the nodes is a bit more straightforward, but obviously you have to specify the precise structure of the tree you want - you can't just specify the relationships as you can with the graph drawing libraries.

## Complete Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{
  >=Stealth[], % does work
}

\begin{document}

% modified from 406 of manual, and using Gonzalo Medina's comment (below)
\tikz [tree layout] \graph [math nodes, nodes={draw, circle, minimum size = .5cm}, sibling sep=0pt]
{aaaa [as=$\land$] -> {aa [as=$\lnot$] -> a , aaa [as=$\rightarrow$] -> {b , c}} };

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    edge = {->},
    circle,
    minimum size=5mm,
    inner sep=0pt,
    draw,
    math content,
    tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
    anchor=center
  },
  [\land
    [\lnot
      [a]
    ]
    [\rightarrow
      [b]
      [c]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

## EDIT

If you prefer to stick to the old syntax for trees, you can do that so long as you don't mix it in problematic ways with the graph drawing environment.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  my tree/.style={
    ->,
    nodes={draw, circle, minimum size = .5cm},
    >=Stealth[],
  },
}
\begin{document}
\tikz [ my tree ]
  \node {$\land$}
  child {
    node {$\lnot$}
    child {
      node {$a$}
    }
  }
  child {
    node {$\rightarrow$}
    child {
      node {$b$}
    }
    child {
      node {$c$}
    }
  };
\end{document}
```

I don't get the problems with overlapping nodes shown in your screenshot ***provided I do not load the `graphdrawing` TikZ library***:

[image: old tree syntax]

Comment: I'm sure there's an easier way (things such as `a^{2}` work out of the box using `math nodes`), but you can say `\tikz[tree layout] 
\graph[math nodes] 
{
a [as=$\land$]
 -> {b [as=$\lnot$] -> c , d [as=$\rightarrow$] -> {e , f}}
};`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you! That's very helpful although it confused me for a while trying to get a, b and c into the right places ;). (I am easily confused, apparently, and extremely unfamiliar with the graph drawing stuff.)